# Remove the square and curly brackets from the column of joined table in Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2008, json-query

I'm using Microsoft SQL server v14.0.1000
I'm using the below query to convert my query result into JSON :

```
SELECT TOP(5) dn.id AS ID,
       dn.EventTimeStamp AS EventTimeStamp,
       dn.ControllerId AS ControllerID,
       JSON_QUERY((SELECT ControllerName
                     FROM Controllers
                    WHERE dn.ControllerId = Controllers.ControllerID
                      FOR JSON PATH, without_array_wrapper)) AS ControllerName
  FROM DashboardNotifications dn
 ORDER BY dn.ID DESC
   FOR JSON PATH
```

And getting the below JSON as a result :

```json
[
  {
    "ID": 354,
    "EventTimeStamp": "2022-05-17T05:35:25",
    "ControllerId": 24,
    "ControllerName": {
      "ControllerName": "P25-SC-0233"
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": 353,
    "EventTimeStamp": "2022-05-17T05:34:20",
    "ControllerId": 17,
    "ControllerName": {
      "ControllerName": "P25-SC-0226"
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": 352,
    "EventTimeStamp": "2022-05-17T05:33:50",
    "ControllerId": 16,
    "ControllerName": {
      "ControllerName": "P25-SC-0225"
    }
  }
]
```

I've been able to remove square brackets from

```json
"ControllerName":[{"ControllerName":"P25-SC-0233"}],
```

although my desired output is :

```json
[
  {
    "ID": 354,
    "EventTimeStamp": "2022-05-17T05:35:25",
    "ControllerId": 24,
    "ControllerName": "P25-SC-0233"
  },
  {
    "ID": 353,
    "EventTimeStamp": "2022-05-17T05:34:20",
    "ControllerId": 17,
    "ControllerName": "P25-SC-0226"
  },
  {
    "ID": 352,
    "EventTimeStamp": "2022-05-17T05:33:50",
    "ControllerId": 16,
    "ControllerName": "P25-SC-0225"
  }
]
```

What changes do I need to make to remove the nested ControllerName key?

Comment: Just remove json_query, no?

Comment: @Salman A removing json_query will infact give ```"ControllerName":"{\"ControllerName\":\"P25-SC-0233\"}"```

Comment: Hard to say without table schema, but it seems like you should be joining on Controllers instead of wrapping it in a subquery.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I swear it didn't work when I tried joining earlier lol.... It's working now, maybe I did some changes this time around. Thanks for making me try join one more time :D

Comment: remove `json_query` AND the `for json` inside the subquery. Or perhaps use a lateral join. Unfortunately you did not provide a runnable example otherwise it would have been easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want the subquery without `FOR JSON` (and then you don't need `JSON_QUERY` to escape it)

```sql
SELECT TOP(5) dn.id AS ID,
       dn.EventTimeStamp AS EventTimeStamp,
       dn.ControllerId AS ControllerID,
       (
           SELECT c.ControllerName
             FROM Controllers c
            WHERE dn.ControllerId = c.ControllerID
       ) AS ControllerName
  FROM DashboardNotifications dn
 ORDER BY dn.ID DESC
   FOR JSON PATH;
```

> Ensure your subquery is guaranteed to return a maximum of one row

You could also just use a join

```sql
SELECT TOP(5) dn.id AS ID,
       dn.EventTimeStamp,
       dn.ControllerId,
       c.ControllerName
  FROM DashboardNotifications dn
  LEFT JOIN
       Controllers c ON dn.ControllerId = c.ControllerID
 ORDER BY dn.ID DESC
   FOR JSON PATH;
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Although I tried something similar to both these approaches before using json_query. Must have done some silly mistake. Funny enough, I'm now unable to reproduce the mistake that I did.

Comment: Got the problem now, I was actually using ```For JSON AUTO``` at the end earlier instead of For JSON PATH, the query was exactly the same as your join query.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need for `json_query`. Change the query to:

```
SELECT TOP(5) dn.id AS ID, dn.EventTimeStamp AS EventTimeStamp, dn.ControllerId AS ControllerID, (
    SELECT ControllerName FROM Controllers WHERE dn.ControllerId = Controllers.ControllerID
) AS ControllerName
FROM DashboardNotifications dn
ORDER BY dn.ID DESC
FOR JSON PATH
```